# Travel mode bicycling no result

Tags: android, directions

If i try to request a path with travel mode bicycling i get org.json.JSONException: Index 0 out of range [0..0)

This is the ulr maker:

```
private String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog, String travelMode){
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    //"&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true"
    Log.d(TAG_LOG, "Travel mode:" + travelMode);
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=" + travelMode + "&alternatives=true");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

And the error is here:

```
final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject overviewPolylines = routes.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
```

why? :(

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the `routeArray` contains no elements. Try entering your URL into a browser and see what the JSON response actually contains.

Comment: Make sure your origin and destination are correct and not separate by any bodies of water. If the locations are dynamic, you should take the possibility that there are no biking routes between the two locations into account. Check the side of the JSONArray first, perhaps, and let the user know that no routes are available.

Comment: But it NEVER works :/ I put two or more markers on the map, then i calculate the route through these markers... and doesn't work. But..ok  :(

Comment: Interesting, I haven't been able to find any way to make the directions API work with lat/lng coordinate parameters either. Works fine with location names, though. Sorry, wish I could be of more help.